# $\rho(f,g)=\int_E \min(1,|f-g|)dm$. Prove that $f_n$ converges to $f$ in measure if and only if $\rho(f_n,f)\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

**Question**:  Suppose $m$ is a finitemeasure on a measurable space $E$.  Define $\rho(f,g)=\int_E \min(1,|f-g|)dm$.  Prove that $f_n$ converges to $f$ in measure if and only if $\rho(f_n,f)\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

**My Thoughts**: For the backwards direction, if $\rho(f_n,f)\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow 0$, then we have that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_E\min(1,|f_n-f|)dm=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_E|f_n-f|dm=0$, and so we have uniform convergence, which implies in measure convergence.  For the forward direction, I am not really sure if I should consider cases, that is, when $1$ is the minimum and then when $f_n-f$ is the minimum and show that if $1$ is the minimum then the statement can't be true, and so $f_n-f$ must be the minimum and then show that the only way we get in measure convergence is if that integral equals $0$... but I am not quite sure how to do that.   Any thoughts, suggestions, etc. are greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

Comment: Something feels wrong. If $\rho(f_n,f)\to 0$ is equivalent to convergence in measure, and it also implies uniform convergence, then convergence in measure implies uniform convergence, but it does not. I think you are wrong in saying that there is uniform convergence.

Comment: How did you make the $\min$ disappear in the $\lim$? With $f_n=n \cdot 1_{[0,{1 \over n}]}$ we see that $f_n \to 0$ ae. and $\int \min(1,|f_n|) \to 0$ but $\int |f_n| = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the backwards direction you don't have uniform convergence, only that $\int_E \min(1,|f_n-f|)\,dm \to 0$. Also, the conclusion $$\int_E \min(1,|f_n-f|)\,dm \to 0 \implies \int_E |f_n-f|\,dm \to 0$$ is not entirely spelled out in your question.

Anyway, for $0 < \varepsilon < 1$ you can use [Markov's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality) to obtain
$$m(|f_n-f| > \varepsilon) =m\Big(\min(1,|f_n-f|) > \varepsilon\Big)\le \frac1\varepsilon \int_E\min(1,|f_n-f|)\,dm \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0.$$

Conversely, assume that $f_n \to f$ in measure $m$ and let $0 < \varepsilon <1$. Pick $n_0 \in \Bbb{N}$ such that for $n \ge n_0$ we have $$m\left(|f_n-f| >\frac\varepsilon{2m(E)}\right) < \frac\varepsilon2.$$
Then for all $n \ge n_0$ we have
\begin{align}
\int_E \min(1,|f_n-f|)\,dm &\le \int_{|f_n-f| \le \frac\varepsilon{2m(E)}} |f_n-f|\,dm + \int_{|f_n-f| > \frac\varepsilon{2m(E)}} 1\,dm\\
&\le \frac\varepsilon{2m(E)}m\left(|f_n-f| \le\frac\varepsilon{2m(E)}\right) + m\left(|f_n-f| >\frac\varepsilon{2m(E)}\right)\\
&\le \frac\varepsilon2 + \frac\varepsilon2\\
&=\varepsilon
\end{align}
so we conclude $\int_E \min(1,|f_n-f|)\,dm \to 0$.

Comment: For the equality $m(|f_n-f|>\epsilon=m(\min(1,|f_n-f|)>\epsilon$, how do we know that this equality holds?  What if $1$ is the minimum here, and not $|f_n-f|$?

Comment: @User7238 Since $\varepsilon < 1$, if $|f_n-f| > \varepsilon$ then also $\min(1,|f_n-f|) > \varepsilon$. Conversely, assume $min(1,|f_n-f|) > \varepsilon$. If $1$ is the minimum, then $|f_n-f| \ge 1 > \varepsilon$ and if $|f_n-f|$ is the minimum, then $|f_n-f| > \varepsilon$.

Comment: @mechanodroid Why $m\left(|f_n-f| >\frac\varepsilon{2m(E)}\right) < \frac\varepsilon2$ ? why m(E) is not in the denominator ? could you please explain it to me Thanks!

Comment: @rose $f_n \to f$ in measure means that for all $\delta > 0$ we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} m(|f_n-f| > \delta) = 0.$$
In other words, for all $\delta, \eta > 0$ there exists $n_0 \in \Bbb{N}$ such that 
$$n \ge n_0 \implies m(|f_n-f| > \delta) < \eta.$$

Now I chose $\delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{2m(E)}$ and $\eta = \frac\varepsilon2$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

$\forall\epsilon>0,\exists N$ s.t. $\forall n\ge N,m(\{x\in E\mid|f_n(x)-f(x)|>\epsilon\})<\epsilon$

$\Rightarrow \forall n\ge N,\rho(f_n,f)=\int_E \min\{1,|f_n-f|\}dm$
$=\int_{\{x\in E\mid|f_n(x)-f(x)|>\epsilon\}}1dm+\int_{E\setminus\{x\in E\mid|f_n(x)-f(x)|>\epsilon\}}|f_n-f|dm<\epsilon+\epsilon\cdot m(E)$

Thus, convergence in measure implies convergence wrt $\rho$.

Conversely,

$\forall\epsilon>0,\exists N$ s.t. $\forall n\ge N,\rho(f_n,f)=\int_E\min\{1,|f_n-f|\}dm<\epsilon$

$\Rightarrow m(\{x\in E\mid|f_n(x)-f(x)|>\epsilon\})\le\int_{\{x\in E\mid|f_n(x)-f(x)|>\epsilon\}}1dm\le\int_E\min\{1,|f_n-f|\}dm<\epsilon$

Thus, convergence wrt $\rho$ implies convergence in measure as well.

Remark. While the definition of convergence measure is stated in a slightly different way (undistinguishing $\epsilon$), you can easily notice that they are the same ones.

Comment: Just a quick question, in your backwards directiion, in the "middle inequality", you are saying that $1$ is the minimum, but wouldn't that only be true if $\epsilon>1$?